# Leaflet: retrieving bounds for a KML polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, kml

I'm inserting polygons into a Leaflet map using a Leaflet plugin called [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore). The syntax I'm using is:

```
var polygon = omnivore.kml('placeName.kml');
polygon.addTo(map);
```

This works great; the polygon appears on my map. However, once it's added I want to then zoom/pan the map to fit the shape as best as possible. I've been trying this:

```
polygon.addTo(map).fitBounds();
```

...but that throws an error: `'fitBounds is not a function'`. I've also tried to find the coordinates using this:

```
polygon.addTo(map).getBounds().getNorthEast();
```

...but that comes back with `'cannot read property 'lat' of undefined'`.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm stumped. Documentation is [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html) and I'm using Leaflet 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait till the `.kml` has loaded. So do your stuff after the `'ready'` event has fired, stated in the docs [HERE](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore):

```
var polygon = omnivore.kml('yourKML.kml');
polygon.addTo(map);

polygon.on('ready', function() {
    map.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds())
});
```

Comment: I knew it would be something I'd overlooked! Thank you so much for your help. Is there anything in particular that tipped you off to the fact that it was a timing issue? The 'undefined' part maybe? @Manuel

Comment: Yes i saw it in the console that the .getBounds() method get called before the .kml is comletely loaded